# which database engine is best for full text search on a 10M rows table?

Tags: database, full-text-search

I'm creating a search engine and needs to search keywords in a text field (about 300 words, unstructured).

I'm thinking about noSQL\MySQL+Sphinx, the performance impact here is crucial.

which DB engine should I use?